# How to find text using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, search

So this is my code for looking for the price.

`a = prompt("Link?")
window.location = a
var priceElement = document.getElementById('UserSalesTab').getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].getElementsByTagName('b')[0]; // Get the element that contains the price
var price = parseInt(priceElement.innerHTML.match(/\d+/));`

Comment: post an example snippet of HTML

Comment: This is impossible. You need some reference on the page to go by, some element to search inside to make the search much less broad. Give us the HTML for this "price" and some of the surrounding elements.

Comment: <b style="color: Green;">R$980</b>

Comment: @nPwn show whole code, not just the element that you want to find.

Comment: My code or the whole HTML code of the page?

Comment: @nPwn - and put the code into your original post (use the Edit button), not in a comment.

Comment: Okay well this page has a ton of HTML, here is the link: http://www.roblox.com/Red-RAWR-item?id=66330295

Comment: @nPwn your code is really not understandable, if you change window.location your code can not work any more, you haven't said that how you run this code yet?

Comment: It's a notepad doc. I just click it and it opens a window in my browser. I then make it go to the link and try to run those next two lines but it's not happening...

Comment: if that's a userscript as you said, userscripts don't work like this. you can add @include lines at the top of the usercript and it works only on the page that you want, [example](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Globs),
if you want to get pages from another websites, the way is not window.location, you have to use [cross domain xhr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests), so it's more complicate and you should ask it as a new question, if you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

are you posting to another page or are you getting the same number from the same location always on the same page? 
If thats the case you can use.

```
     var myvar = document.getElementById('myfield').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Well it is on any page but the thing I am looking for will always be in the same place.

Comment: myField would be the ID of the html Element that you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would find the least expensive price on any product page on the website you mentioned that has a Private Sales list when on the right page (such as http://www.roblox.com/Red-RAWR-item?id=66330295):

```
if (window.location.href.match(/http:\/\/www.roblox.com\/.*?\?id=\d+/) && document.getElementById('UserSalesLink')) {
    var priceElement = document.getElementById('UserSalesTab').getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].getElementsByTagName('b')[0]; // Get the element that contains the price
    var price = parseInt(priceElement.innerHTML.match(/\d+/)); // Store the price as an int
}
```

Using that code, you will end up with a variable `price` which is an int containing the least expensive price on the page.

I use javascript's [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) method and the [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method to narrow it down to the right div, then I use the [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to extract the numbers from that element, and the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method to store the price as an integer instead of a string.

Comment: myContent...? Is that a method or would I have to write my own variable like document.math...?

Comment: myContent would be the variable (string) with your content with the price and other stuff in it.

Comment: Like what I'm searching for...?

Comment: It would be your whole `<b style="color: Green;">R$980</b>` stored in a variable

Comment: To store that in a variable from the html page you would have to either give it a unique id so that you could use `document.getElementById('myElementID').innerHTML` or use some other method, such as `getElementByTagName()` (not recommended)

Comment: so var myContent = <b style="color: Green;">R$980</b>. Okay so could I just search for <b style=? Because that 980 wouldn't always be 980...

Comment: Almost -- you need to store that as a string, so wrap it in quotes, and remember the semicolon: `var myContent = '<b style="color: Green;">R$980</b>';`

Comment: This is what I have: var myContent = "<b style=";
var price = myContent.match(/\$[\d\.]+/);
price = parseFloat(price.substr(1));
alert(price)    It's not alerting though

Comment: OK slow down... you missed the point of my answer. I think these problems are happening because your question is somewhat vague. If you mean you want to find the price in a string, then you would use regex, as I demonstrate in my answer. If you want to find the tag in the DOM so you can store it in a string, you will need to give us an example of the relevant page code so we can show you how to get it from the DOM.

Comment: Here is the link of what I'm finding it one. If you scroll down you'll find the prices. I guess you inspect element and find it. http://www.roblox.com/Red-RAWR-item?id=66330295

Comment: What are you trying to find this with? A userscript for Greasemonkey?

Comment: Just the first price there. I am making a program that will help me buy it if it is a price that I want.

Comment: Thank you but that finds the recent average price. If you scroll down even more you'll find a bunch of prices selling by people.

Comment: I've just updated it to get only the price in the top right corner of page, the normal price, I think

Comment: It's all the way at the bottom, it will say Private Sales. Maybe you have to be logged on to see it but I don't think so.

Comment: I found it, but there's a whole list of prices -- which one do you want?

Comment: The one that is the least amount

Comment: Thank you!!! So in my code I have a prompt and the user posts the link in that and it will take it to that page. Can the code still run once the location of the window is changed?

Comment: If you mean "will that code work on a different page?", the answer is: that code will work on any product page (such as the example you gave) that has a Private Sales list. -- All my code does is store the contents of that particular element to a variable, so if it is run on a page with that particular element, it will work.

Comment: The only way your code is going to work is if my code is run only when you get to that page. Since I don't know the context your code is being used in, I really can't tell you whether that will work.

Comment: It's in an HTML document. So how could I wait until it gets there?

Comment: I need to know what the CONTEXT is. Where is your javascript code being used? If it's being used in a userscript, you could check the url to figure out if it's on the right page, and then run the code. If you're just including this code in your website, then you will never be able to run my code, and what you really need is a cross-domain XMLHTTP request, which doesn't exist currently.

Comment: Yes just a userscript written in notepad. So how could I make it wait to find if it's on the right page?

Comment: It is but what if the location isn't that? Then it will skip that and end the script right?

Comment: @nPwn please remember to mark this as "Accepted" if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make sure the element that contains the price information (in your case, the `b` tag [which, by the way, is [not recommended](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags)]) has an `id` or unique class (nonsense phrase intended) applied to it. This way, we can target that element specifically with Javascript and pull its text.

Once you apply an `id` or class, this is what your code should look like:

```
var myElem = document.getElementById("price"),
    price = myEleme.textContent;
```

The first line assigns the element we're targeting to the variable `myElem`. The second line sets the variable `price` to the element's text value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function xpath(xpath, element) {
        if (!element)
            element = document;
        return document.evaluate(xpath, element, null,
                                 XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    }

var prices  = xpath("//table[@class='ItemSalesTable']/tbody/tr/td[3]");
//now prices is an array of price elements

prices.snapshotItem(0).innerHTML; // price ( ignore this one )    
prices.snapshotItem(1).innerHTML; // <b style="color: Green;">R$900</b>
prices.snapshotItem(2).innerHTML; // <b style="color: Green;">R$975</b>
prices.snapshotItem(3).innerHTML; // <b style="color: Green;">R$980</b>

prices.snapshotLength(); // 11
```

Comment: @nPwn how did you tried it? Is your program an userscript? where did you put this in your code? I tried it on javascript console and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Well I have the user paste the link into a prompt and then the page takes it to that page. Does the script stop running once the location is changed...?